# How to change the label tooltip of mat paginator (next and previous buttons)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an issue where i can see the labels on next and previous hover .
How can i remove them or modify them.

**HTML**

```
<mat-paginator #paginator 
    [length]="totalAssetsLength" 
    [pageSize]="10" 
    [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50]" 
    (page)="pageEvent($event)" > </mat-paginator>
```

**TS**:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) 
set paginator(value: MatPaginator) { this.actualPaginator = value; }
```

[image: R]

Comment: Please view the image to know more

Comment: -- HTML :  --
<mat-paginator #paginator [length]="totalAssetsLength" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50]" (page)="pageEvent($event)" > </mat-paginator>

-- Ts --
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false})
  set paginator(value: MatPaginator) {
    this.actualPaginator = value;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new instance of mat paginator will help you :

Simply add this to your component where you are using mat-paginator.

```
export class CustomMatPaginatorIntl extends MatPaginatorIntl {
  
  nextPageLabel     = '';
  previousPageLabel = '';
}
```

In **material.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatPaginatorModule, MatPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { MatAutocompleteModule,
         MatFormFieldModule,
         MatRadioModule,
         MatCardModule } from '@angular/material';
**import { CustomMatPaginatorIntl } from '../pages/asset-list/asset-list.component';**

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatSelectModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatCardModule,
    
  

  ],
  exports: [
    MatSelectModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatCardModule,
    
  ],
  **providers: [{provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: CustomMatPaginatorIntl}]**
})
export class MaterialModule {

 }
```

This would help you out , you can visit
https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api

for more

Answer (score 1):

In your component class, you need to get a reference to `MatPaginator` using `@ViewChild`. Through this reference, you get access to the [MatPaginatorIntl](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#MatPaginatorIntl) service that lets you changes the different labels.

The following example would hide tool-tips for previous and next buttons.

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;

ngOnInit() {
    const paginatorIntl = this.paginator._intl;
    paginatorIntl.nextPageLabel = '';
    paginatorIntl.previousPageLabel = '';
}
```

The following example would change the tool-tips for previous and next buttons.

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;

ngOnInit() {
    const paginatorIntl = this.paginator._intl;
    paginatorIntl.nextPageLabel = '+ 1 page';
    paginatorIntl.previousPageLabel = '- 1 page';
}
```